# GridBagLayout fixed widths for buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, gridbaglayout

Is it possible to have fixed sizes (widths) for buttons in a GridBagLayout, so that they are all the same size always? Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Is there a way to add a padding inside of my JPanel so that the buttons are not too close to my border, or do I draw another JPanel inside the JPanel and move the buttons there?

Comment: As I recall GridBagConstraints.remainder allows you to specify whether a cell should expand or not

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as noted in comments, use GridLayout.

To add padding, just use the last two parameters for GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)

Comment: +1 for `GridLayout`. @jadrijan: You want to use a layout that lets the button adopt it's preferred size, as `FontMetrics` vary by platform.